# disable edit mode right after a column click on ultrawingrid

Tags: vb.net, infragistics

Am trying to disable edit mode as soon as i click a checkbox that i have in a column in my ultrawingrid. I managed to disable edit mode on the rest of the rows, but my last clicked item stays on edit mode and that changes my values. Any ideas of how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, to force exiting from edit mode you call this method

```
yourGrid.PerformAction(UltraGridAction.ExitEditMode)
```

then you could procede with disabling the edit mode for all the row

Comment: nvm i managed to fix it with a combination of your code. thank you m8